# How to call multiple multiline commands in a yml script?

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm not quite sure how to add a multiline script with multiple commands in a yml file of my CI - which is in my case a `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
production:
    stage: deploy
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
    script:
        - while IFS='-' read -r dom app; do
            docker stop "$dom-$app" || true &&
            docker rm "$dom-$app" || true 
            docker run
               --name "$dom-$app"
               --detach
               --restart=always
               -e VIRTUAL_HOST=$dom
               "$dom-$app":latest
        done < $FILE
```

So what I'm doing here is to read a file with a list of apps. For each line I have to stop the existing docker image, remove it and run the new one with some parameters.

1. How do I have to connect the docker commands (stop, rm and run)? Maybe a `&&`?
2. Do I have to use `"` for `$dom-$app`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to create multiline strings in YAML.

The way you are using the multiline plain string, all lines will be folded together with spaces.

Also your last line of the string isn't indented enough.

Longer strings like that should be quoted, because chances are high that there is a `:`  or  `#` inside the string which is special in YAML.

I suggest using literal block style, because that means the text will be interpreted exactly as you see it:

```
    script:
    - |
      while IFS='-' read -r dom app; do
        docker stop "$dom-$app" || true
        docker rm "$dom-$app" || true 
        docker run \
         --name "$dom-$app" \
         --detach \
         --restart=always \
         -e VIRTUAL_HOST=$dom \
         "$dom-$app":latest
      done < $FILE
```

(Note that sequences (items starting with `-`) don't have to be indented, that's why the `-` is directly below `script`.)

You can find more information about YAML quoting styles on my website:
https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html

Comment: Thank. Do I have to quote my variables? In `name` parameter I did it, in `VIRTUAL_HOST` I did not... And do I need the `&&` at the end of each command? In the first I did it, in the second not..

Comment: Quoting in bash is always a good idea if the variables can possibly contain spaces, for example. So if you are not sure, quote it. But that is a pure bash question. If you use `&&` to concatenate two commands then the second one will only be executed if the first succeeded. So it depends on how you want your script to behave.