# How to run multiple lines command in docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose, sh

I am trying to make this run but it retrieves this error:

```
fscrawler           | sed: -e expression #2, char 31: unknown option to `s'
```

I'm trying to run this command:

```
command: >
  sh -c "sed -i -e "s/{ELASTIC_PASSWORD}/${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}/g" 
  -e "s/{ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}/${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}/g" 
  -e "s/{FSCRAWLER_HOST}/${FSCRAWLER_HOST}/g" /root/.fscrawler/job1/_settings.yaml 
  && fscrawler job1 --restart --rest"
```

I've tried with simple quotes and many other options (backslashes at the end as well) but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Move the commands into entrypoint file and call the file in the command

Comment: why cannot be within command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call multiple multiline commands in a yml script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870579/how-to-call-multiple-multiline-commands-in-a-yml-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

### docker-compose.yml

```
entrypoint: /path/to/entrypoint.sh
environment:
  - ELASTIC_HOST=${ELASTIC_HOST}
  - ELASTIC_USER=${ELASTIC_USER}
  - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
  - FSCRAWLER_HOST=${FSCRAWLER_HOST}
```

### Dockerfile FSCrawler

```
...
COPY /host/path/to/entrypoint.sh /docker/path/to/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod u+x /entrypoint.sh
```

### Entrypoint

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -e "s|{ELASTIC_USER}|${ELASTIC_USER}|g" \
-e "s|{ELASTIC_PASSWORD}|${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}|g" \
-e "s|{ELASTIC_HOST}|${ELASTIC_HOST}|g" \
-e "s|{FSCRAWLER_HOST}|${FSCRAWLER_HOST}|g" /root/.fscrawler/job1/_settings.yaml 

fscrawler job1 --restart --rest
```